# Paypal error 404 on Payment.Get()

Tags: paypal

I followed the first steps to paypal... I have everything fixed 
the id in web.config and the secret too...

but this line :

```
var payment = Payment.Get(apiContext, "PAY-0XL713371A312273YKE2GCNI");
```

give me error 404

also.. I have this line

```
apiContext.HTTPHeaders("some-header-name") = "some-value"
```

what do we write for : some header name : and for : some value :

can you help me with that..

the steps I followed are at this page :
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/wiki/Make-Your-First-Call

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The call to `Payment.Get` will return a 404 if the payment you're requesting doesn't exist on the account you're using - in this case you're attempting to locate the example payment id, which will not exist on your account. The fact that you're getting a 404 rather than a [400, 401 or 403](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/errors/) is encouraging as it means you're successfully logging in.